# Getting java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.faces.component.UIComponent.getPassThroughAttributes(Z)Ljava/util/Map;

Tags: primefaces, jboss7.x, jsf-2.2

Initially the application was working with JSF 2.1 jars but now as i added JSF 2.2 jars to respective modules in JBoss 7.1 it shows

```
 java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.faces.component.UIComponent.getPassThroughAttributes(Z)Ljava/util/Map;
```

As i kept JSF jars in JBoss modules then there should not be any conflict between WEB-INF/lib and JBoss Jars

```
Note:
```

- There are no deployment issues with application i.e WAR is getting
  created without any issue
- JSF jars are not added to the WEB-INF/lib
  as it is managed at server level

Edit 1
I have added JSF dependencies through jboss-deployment-structure.xml but still have same issue

Edit 2
I get this error when i try to access the application

Comment: Is I am missing something? if yes please let me know

Comment: Hello @pis. Did you get the answer for this problem? Even I am facing the same issue after migrating from JSF 2.1.17 to 2.2.28.